# How to add link on datatables into data in table

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

I have data on table using Model View Controller :

controller :

```
<tbody>
      @php
      $no=0;
      @endphp
      @foreach ($pns as $i)
    <tr class="even pointer">
      <td class="a-center ">{{ ++$no }}</td>
      <td class=" "><a href="project/pns/{{ $i->id }}">{{ $i->users->nama}}</a></td>
      <td class=" ">{{ $i->NIP_lama}}</td>
      <td class=" ">{{ $i->NIP_baru}}</td>
      <td class=" ">{{ $i->TMT_CPNS}}</td>
      <td class=" ">{{ $i->TMT_PNS}}</td>
      <td class=" ">{{ $i->TMT_gol_ruang}}</td>
      <td class=" ">{{ $i->master_golongan->golongan}}</td>  
      <td class=" ">{{ $i->master_jabatan->nama_jabatan}}</td>

    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
```

And the Controller :

```
public function pns() {
    $pns = Data_pns::with('users')->get();
    return view('admin.pns',['pns' => $pns]);
}
```

its run normally and not having error . now I want to add datatables yajra yajra feature , and it has 1 problem . **I dont know** how to add link :

```
<td class=" "><a href="project/pns/{{ $i->id }}">{{ $i->users->nama}}</a></td>
```

on the datatables :

My View :

```
    @push('scripts')
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $('#table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            responsive: true,
            ajax: '{!! route('d_pns') !!}',
            columns: [
                { data: 'DT_RowIndex', name: 'DT_RowIndex', orderable: false,searchable: false},
                { data: 'users.nama', name: 'users.nama'},
                { data: 'NIP_lama', name: 'NIP_lama'},
                { data: 'NIP_baru', name: 'NIP_baru'},
                { data: 'TMT_CPNS', name: 'TMT_CPNS'},
                { data: 'TMT_PNS', name: 'TMT_PNS'},
                { data: 'TMT_gol_ruang', name: 'TMT_gol_ruang'},
                { data: 'master_golongan.golongan', name: 'master_golongan.golongan'},
                { data: 'master_jabatan.nama_jabatan', name: 'master_jabatan.nama_jabatan'},

            ],
        });
    })
</script>
@endpush
```

and my controller like this :

```
 public function indexDataTables_pns()
{

    $pns = Data_pns::with('users','master_golongan','master_jabatan')->get();


    return Datatables::of($pns)->addIndexColumn()
    ->make(true);

}
```

## edited this controller

and my controller like this :

```
 public function indexDataTables_pns()
{

    $pns = Data_pns::with('users','master_golongan','master_jabatan')->get();


    return Datatables::of($pns)->addIndexColumn()
        ->addColumn('Nama', function ($pns) {
        return '<a href="project/pns/'.$pns->id.'">'.$pns->users->nama.'</a>';
    })
    ->make(true);

}
```

but this output in view "  <#a href="project/pns/5">test" with out #

my Question how to add link like

```
<td class=" "><a href="project/pns/{{ $i->id }}">{{ $i->users->nama}}</a></td>
```

on datatbles ?

Comment: I *think* maybe you're talking about the jQuery "datatable" plugin from a PHP/Laravel back-end.  If so, look here: https://medium.com/justlaravel/how-to-implement-datatables-in-laravel-f8470e73b429

Comment: i think its diferent ,this thread is 2016 , and i using Yajra datatbles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you already halfway there, you need to set the 'Nama' columns as raw, if you're returning an html content like this

```
 public function indexDataTables_pns()
{
$pns = Data_pns::with('users','master_golongan','master_jabatan')->get();

return Datatables::of($pns)->addIndexColumn()
    ->addColumn('Nama', function ($pns) {
    return '<a href="project/pns/'.$pns->id.'">'.$pns->users->nama.'</a>';
})
->rawColumns(['Nama'])
->make(true);

}
```